# Use of super in multi level inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code as follows:

```
class A():
    def something():
        #Do something

class B(A):
    def something():
        super(B, self).something()
        #Do something

class C(B):
    def something():
        if VeryRareSpecificCase:
            super(super(C,self)).something()
        else:
            super(C, self).something()
        #Do something
```

However, it raises the error TypeError: must be type, not super.

Comment: What did you expect `super(super(C, self))` to refer to? If the answer is `super(B, self)`, then you aren't using `super` correctly; you should just be hardcoding the class references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you aren't using a complicated diamond inheritance, you can skip a parent in the chain with this approach:

```
class C(B):
    def something(self):
        if VeryRareSpecificCase:
            super(B, self).something()  # <-- note: B passed explicitly!
        else:
            super().something()
```

If you really have just `C --> B --> A --> object`, as shown in your MCVE, this should be safe.  However, if you have something more complicated than that, you'll have to work with the [mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) directly and specify exactly what behaviour you need manually.

Comment: I'm importing B from another module before inheriting it and A is in a module I don't want to access. Would this affect anything or can I still do this?